# Calling a function within a jQuery plug-in

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am in the process of creating my first jQuery plug-in that will format numbers automatically to various international formats. There are a couple functions within the plug-in that strips the strings and re-formats the string that needs to be called from another jQuery script.

Based on the plug-in structure below (let me know if you need the entire code) can I call and send the parameter(s) to the `stripFormat(ii)` and `targetFormat(ii, iv)` functions?

Or do I need to change my plug-in structure and if so how?

```
    (function($){
        var p = $.extend({
            aNum: '0123456789',
            aNeg: '-',
            aSep: ',',
            aDec: '.',
            aInput: '',
            cPos: 0
        });

        $.fn.extend({
             AutoFormat: function() {
                return this.each(function() {
                    $(this).keypress(function (e){
                        code here;
                    });

                    $(this).keyup(function (e){
                        code here;
                    });

                    // Would like to call this function from another jQuery script - see below.
                    function stripFormat(ii){
                        code here;
                    }

                    // Would like to call this function from another jQuery script - see below.
                    function targetFormat(ii, iv){
                        code here;
                    }

                });

            }
        });

    })(jQuery);
```

Methods trying to call the plug-in functions:

```
    jQuery(function(){
            $("input").change(function (){ //temp function to demonstrate the stripFormat() function.
                document.getElementById(targetElementid).value = targetFormat(targetElementid, targetValue);
            });
    });
```

I have tried to use these variations without success:

```
    document.getElementById(targetElementid).value = $.targetFormat(targetElementid, targetValue);
    document.getElementById(targetElementid).value = $.autoFormat().targetFormat(targetElementid, targetValue);
```

Answer (score -1):

Well I would probably do it more like this plugin: http://www.stilldesigning.com/dotstring/jquery.string.1.0.js

```
$.string(" <p>this is a test</p> ").strip().stripTags().capitalize().str
> 'This is a test'
```

Or take a look at currency format, takes a value and options object.  This seems it woudl work for your situation only with other formatting.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/currencyFormat

```
$('#some_element').currency() //will format the text of the element
$.currency(123456.78,{options}) //formats number and returns string
```

Also, confused about using `document.getElementById("targetElement").value` instead of just `$("targetElement").val()` or `$("targetElement").html()`

Comment: Ryan,

Thanks for your suggestions. Here is a link to my plugin 

http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Your suggestions are welcomed.

Bob

Comment: Thanks for the complement.

No it is not complete - I am still trying to figure a way to call the sub functions stripFormat() && targetFormat() from another script. I can them from inside but that defeats the purpose of have a re-usable plugin.

Any other ideas? (maybe a beer!)

Bob